# Don’t select extension buy default "Save" dialog

Tags: finder, dialog

If I’m not mistaking, before I changed computer, the extension wasn’t selected in the "Save" dialog. Is there a way to achieve that?

[image: Save as dialog]

Comment: Hard to tell quite what you're asking - as all the docs in the folder have visible extensions, it could be a macOS setting… but as they're all Adobe docs it could be an Adobe pref

Comment: It’s the same in all apps, so it’s definitely a Mac thing (and driving me crazy…)

Comment: FWIW, I don't see this in all apps: only some third-party apps. But the behaviour is different between Mojave and Catalina for the same apps. I suspect it's a bug.